# Are Spring's cache annotations safe to use when evictions are involved?

Tags: java, spring, caching, spring-cache

I am using Spring 4.0.3, and utilizing the Cache Abstraction feature, backed by EhCache 2.8.1.

I was concerned that the method-level annotations `@Cacheable` and `@CacheEvict` may not properly lock the cache while editing it, resulting in thread safety problems. My test below seems to confirm that. My question is, am I misusing the framework or misinterpreting the results of my test? Or am I correct in concluding that the annotations do not cause the cache to be properly locked, and therefore the use of `@CacheEvict` does not guarantee that future reads will be valid?

Test:

**Create a database table to store a counter value**

```
create table counter
(
    counter integer
);
insert into counter values(0);
```

**Create an entry in ehcache.xml to cache the counter value**

```
<cache name="counter"
    eternal="true"
    maxElementsInMemory="1"/>
```

**Create two request mapping methods in a Spring controller -- one to read the value of the counter and return after a long delay, and the other to increment the value and then return quickly**

```
@RequestMapping("/viewcounter")
@ResponseBody
@Cacheable(value = "counter", key = "1")
public int readCounter() {
    int count = dao.selectInteger("select counter from counter");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return count;
}

@RequestMapping("/incrementcounter")
@ResponseBody
@CacheEvict(value = "counter", key = "1")
public int incrementCounter() {
    dao.update("update counter set counter = counter + 1");
    int count = dao.selectInteger("select counter from counter");
    return count;
}
```

**Follow these three steps under two different scenarios -- first with the cache annotations removed from the controller methods, and then with them added back in**

1. Visit `/incrementcounter`
2. In one browser tab, visit `/viewcounter`, and then immediately after initiating this request, visit `/incrementcounter` in another tab
3. Visit `/viewcounter`

**Test results**

```
Expected result: 2
Actual result without caching: 2
Actual result with caching: 1
```

The with-caching result is wrong, yes?

Comment: No it is what I would expect. the `count` at the moment of selection is 1 (you update it afterwards). That value is returned and as such cached.

Comment: @M.Deinum I think that you're talking about the results for step 2. Yes, at that point, /viewcounter should show a value of 1. But I'm talking about the results for step 3. That request is not initiated until two calls to /incrementcounter have been executed, so the correct result should be the value 2.

Comment: For step 3 the value is still 1 as that is the cached value.

Comment: @M.Deinum I understand _why_ I'm seeing 1, but I'm calling that a concurrency bug. I think reads should always return the actual value at the time that the read was initiated. If the reads and writes during step 2 had been locked to prevent interleaving, step 3 would have shown the correct result. My point is that I assumed the cache annotations would implement that locking for me, and it looks like that assumption is wrong.

Comment: I still don't see the problem. You call a method, the result of the query is 1. In between you do a database update and a cache evict. Thread is still waiting... Then it returns and that is the point where the result is cached. The second call to `/viewcounter` returns the cached result. How locking is handled (or not) depends on the cache implementation used I guess. Spring only delegates to underlying mechanism it is only a wrapper it doesn't add functionality.

Comment: There's no locking in the cache abstraction. If you want these features, you need your cache to be transactional, not the caching abstraction.

Comment: @StéphaneNicoll Thanks. If you write that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no locking in the cache abstraction. You are [not the first one asking for it](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9304) and we already had significant brainstorming internally of what it would cost to support it. It turns out that it is far from being simple and playing with locks in such abstraction may be very tricky, especially in a "generic" way. Also, cache vendors spend a significant amount of resources to support these kind of use cases and there's a reason for that.

My best guess at it for the moment is that if you want these features, you need your cache to be transactional. There are some gotcha when using it with the abstraction though, check in particular [SPR-11540](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11540) which is being worked on at the moment.